# Numeric reference style sorted after order of appearance, accepting a author year style library

Tags: bibliographies

I am having issues with my references. What I want is numeric references in square brakets, that are sorted after order of appearance (not after the author last name) in both the text and the references list. And I want the references to compress and sort for multiple entries.

I produce my .bib file with Mendeley - meaning it is not a "numeric" file, but author-year based.

When I used the template from MDPI journals it does this beautifully <3. Unfortunately I cannot make that .sty file work as it is loading some packages/options in the template I have no idea what are... (and I can't use the template as I need a different output for my thesis).

I realise you want an MWE, but I just need some help on where to start.

Comment: Generally `.bib` files can be used with any bibliography/citation style as long as the entries contain the required data. If your entries look fine in an author-year style the should look equally good in a numeric style. The point of `.bib` files is rather that they contain the raw entry data and that you can select any citation/bibliography style you want with little extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

I found an option to make it work, for any others out there with the same issues. The natbib package with the following options + hyperref package.

Then using the .bst you can find here: [MDPI_latex](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)

```
\usepackage[sort&compress, numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage[]{hyperref} 
\newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=#1}} %needed for mdpi bst file. 

\bibliographystyle{mdpi.bst}
\bibliography{mylibrary.bib} %your bib file
```

Comment: Note that strictly speaking \*`\bibliographystyle{mdpi.bst}` should be `\bibliographystyle{mdpi}` and \*`\bibliography{mylibrary.bib}` should be `\bibliography{mylibrary}`. Both commands take their (file name) arguments *without* file extension (`.bst` or `.bib`). The files may be found nonetheless, but this is not guaranteed on all systems (on older MikTeX systems, for example, the `.bib` file would not be found it the file extension was erroneously included).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `biblatex`? It is as simple as

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}
.....
\begin{document}
.....
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

By default, the backend is `biber` (which understands utf8), but you can add the option  `[backend=bibtex]` if you prefer, at the cost of losing some advanced features.